# Nested hosts with scp?

Tags: ssh, unix, scp

I need a way of copying a file through nested servers, as in

```
localhost$ ssh user@host1
host1$ ssh host2
```

where host2 is on an off-site intranet and not directly accessible.

Is there a way of using scp to copy a file to localhost from host2 through host1 in a single command? Or am I stuck first copying the file to host1 first?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do Multihop SCP transfers?](http://serverfault.com/questions/37629/how-do-i-do-multihop-scp-transfers)

Comment: Yes, didn't see that.

Answer (score 4):

What you're really looking for is a way to [tunnel SSH connections](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html).  I.e.,

```
ssh -f host1 -L 16384:host2:22 -N
```

This will setup a tunnel on *host1* that tunnels *host1:16384* to *host2:22*.  So when you run `ssh host1:16384`, you'll actually connect to *host2*.  See the link for more in depth information and a nifty howto.