# rsync unique situation

Tags: rsync, scp

Reference:
[How do I do Multihop SCP transfers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/37629/how-do-i-do-multihop-scp-transfers)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732039/rsyncing-files-between-two-remote-servers-get-errors-stating-rsync-command-not
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=748431

I have a situation that I really hope there is a solution for, although I've found nothing yet over the last couple of hours.

I have two servers that cannot talk to each other that I need to transfer data between. That's a fairly common situation that is easily overcome with some scp trickery. Here is the gotcha.

One server is accessed over a VPN, `vpnserver` the other server `targetserver` is accessed via a jump host `jumphostserver`.

I have `ProxyCommand` setup to allow me to proxy connections through `jumphostserver` to `targetserver` and I'm using the SSH Mux stuff (`ControlMaster`/`ControlPersist`/`ControlPath`) to allow connection sharing for all connections that are open.

My local machine can properly scp things between the two servers using the following command:

`scp -3 vpnserver:/path/to/file targetserver:/path/to/destination`

I can also rsync things directly from `vpnserver` to my local machine and from my local machine to `targetserver` (using the ssh proxy that goes through `jumphostserver`)

What I need to do is make my machine act as an intermediary the way that `scp -3` allows it to, but do so using `rsync`, so that permissions, ownership, and (more importantly) the ACLs are properly copied to `targetserver`.

I had thought about trying to NFS export the filesystem of `vpnserver` and `targetserver` (re-exported through `jumphostserver`), but I don't have control over `jumphostserver`, only over `vpnserver` and `targetserver`.

Comment: Yet another problem that doesn't exist in an IPv6 network. Hope you plan to deploy it soon. :)

Comment: Isolated LANs that can't reach each other can be done in IPv6, too.  I've done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of these two hosts could log into the other if the network connectivity were present, either with an SSH ID key on one recognized in authorized_keys on the other, or a password can be used, AND if port forwarding is not disabled, AND if running this traffic through your local machine is OK, then this can almost always be done via port forwarding.

Let's call your local machine host A, and that host B has the credentials to log into host C with SSH if only it could reach host C.

1. Log in to host B using the option to do REVERSE port forwarding listening to port 2222 on machine B and connecting to port 3333 on localhost (which will happen on machine A).  On Linux this option is "**-R 2222:localhost:3333**".
2. Log in to host C using normal port forwarding listening to port 3333 on machine A and connecting tp port 22 on localhost (which will happen on machine C).  On Linux this option is "**-L 3333:localhost:22**".
3. On host B start a test SSH session to host C to see if everything is set up right.  The command to do is "**ssh -p2222 usernameonhostc@localhost**".  If all is set up right, it will connect to port 2222 on B, be forwarded to port 3333 on A, and then be forwarded to port 22 on C.  If your keys are right, you can just login.  Otherwise you should ge a password prompt.  Enter the password to be sure.

If you can connect OK, close that test connection, and proceed with either #4 or #5 below.

4. To send files from B to C, do this on B:  **rsync -e "ssh -p2222" -av /where/to/get/files/. usernameonhostc@localhost:/where/to/put/files**
5. To send files from C to B, do this on B:  rsync -e "**ssh -p2222" -av usernameonhostc@localhost:/where/to/get/files/. /where/to/put/files**

If you need to transfer very large amounts of data between the machines over the internet because your local access has limited bandwidth, then it will be more complicated, require knowing how the networks are restricted on B and C, and may not even be possible.

Substitute the string "useronhostc" with your username that you use on host C.  Leave "localhost" as is or change it only to "127.0.0.1".  Provide the correct paths for the examples shown.  Remove the "**/.**" at the end of the source path if it is just a single file.

Remember you must login to both B and C (from A) at the same time.  Separate xterminal windows is suggested.  These ssh logins will both be doing port forwarding.  But you can also do commands through them.  You could choose different port numbers than 2222 or 333 shown by example.  Port 22 is probably require unless host C listens on a different port for some reason (I do that with my servers ... I'm not telling what port).  If you change ports 2222 and/or 3333 you probably have to use numbers 1024 or above.  Technically, you can even use the same number for both since the listens are on different machines.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: Turns out the company has ACLs in place on the switches to prevent SSH from the remote host backward through the VPN. I'm going to have to tarball and scp -3 the tarball instead of using rsync. Selecting yours as the best answer, however.

Comment: ACLs (iptable) inside the machine blocking all ports to localhost?  Or maybe an sshd config to disable port forwarding?  Maybe you can rsync to your localhost then rsync from there to the other host.

Comment: A switch cannot be configured to block something inside an SSH session because the traffic is encrypted.  They'd have to be doing it in the host.

Comment: The switch blocks all connections backward through the VPN tunnel. So I can initiate a connection to any machine on the VPN from my machine, but the remote machines in the DC cannot initiate a connection to my machine. Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If both systems have access to the internet, you could install the [n2n package from ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/n2n/) to create a host-to-host VPN link between the systems.

Comment: They do both have access, but I need to do this over the private network so that I'm not eating up the customers' bandwidth allocation in either environment. Thanks for the info tho, that could come in handy for other projects coming up.

Comment: You can limit the speed of your `rsync` transfer with the `--bwlimit` flag.

Comment: Bandwidth is not the same as throughput. I was referring to the amount of data they are permitted to transfer per month, not how fast it transfers. :-)