# SCP version of - ssh -A -t -l root 192.16.4.9 ssh -A -t node-17

Tags: ssh, linux-networking, scp

I'm on a vpn. I ssh to a machine through another machine like so

ssh -A -t -l bob 192.16.4.9 ssh -A -t node-17

I now need to scp a file from node-17:/tmp/something.

How can I do the above in one step? There is no space left on the other nodes to move it to first. I should add that public keys are used to authenticate between 192.168.4.9 and node-17

Thanks

Comment: likely duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/37629/how-do-i-do-multihop-scp-transfers/221187

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `-t` options, but what I think you want is

```
ssh -At -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -At -l bob 192.16.4.9' node-17
```

Then the same method works with scp, e.g.

```
scp -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -At -l bob 192.16.4.9' file node-17:file
```

To make this connection configuration permanent so you don't have to reenter it every time, put the following into your ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host node-17
ProxyCommand ssh -At -l bob 192.16.4.9
```

Then all you'll need to run is `ssh -At node-17` or `scp file node-17:file`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SCP you could just `cat` the file on the remote machine and save the output locally.

```
ssh -A -t -l bob 192.16.4.9 ssh -A -t node-17 cat /tmp/something > /local/copy/of/something
```

You can also use this in the other direction to upload a file to the remote machine, but with an extra hop it requires some creative quoting on the command line:

```
ssh -A -t -l bob 192.16.4.9 'ssh -A -t node-17 "cat > /tmp/new-file"' < /local/copy/of/new-file
```